# Using Ray Tasks inside a Ray Serve Deployment

Tags: python, distributed-computing, ray

I have a use case with Ray Serve where the request sent by the user may require a high or low computational need and there is going to be a logic that will determine the number of Ray tasks to be spawned.

I know we can use different deployments inside another deployment but what I need here is a functionality like ray.wait().

Is it possible to use Ray Tasks inside a Ray Serve deployment and if so would it be a good practice?